# php not working inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

The code below is not working properly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap(){
    var center = {lat:9.93,lng:76.9}
    var mapOption = {zoom: 10,center: center,/*center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.93,76.9)*/};
    var markerOptions ={position:center};
    //create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOption);

    //create marker
    //var loc_pat = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    //loc_pat.setMap(map);
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mappoints";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[pointLat].', '.$row[pointLong].');';
        }
    ?>

}
```

It is throwing the error:

> warning: Use of undefined constant pointLat - assumed 'pointLat' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP).

and same for pointLng.

Please help.

Comment: This is not an error, this is a warning. Try using `$row["pointLat"]` and `$row["pointLong"]` instead

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried doing what the warning suggested?

Comment: tried using as $row["pointLat"] and $row["pointLong"], still same warning.

Comment: tried using ' insted of " and it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the array index in a quote mark (if you sure you have  *pointLat* and *pointLong*  in row (you can var_dump $row before it for debug))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap(){
    var center = {lat:9.93,lng:76.9}
    var mapOption = {zoom: 10,center: center,/*center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.93,76.9)*/};
    var markerOptions ={position:center};
    //create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOption);

//create marker
//var loc_pat = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
//loc_pat.setMap(map);
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mappoints";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['pointLat'].', '.$row['pointLong'].');';
    }
?>

}
```

of course your solution is buggy because in while  you define just one variable `var myLatlng1` and if $row return multiple results, you just have the last one,  its better to  put them in a list, I mean

```
     echo '  var myLatlng =[]';
     $i = 0 ;
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo 'myLatlng[' . $i . '] = new google.maps.LatLng('.$row['pointLat'].', '.$row['pointLong'].');';
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding the proper content type to php?

```
<?php
// definition of Content Type
@header("Content-type: application/javascript");

// define a simple variable
text= "Hello world!"; 
?>
alert('<?php echo $text; ?>'); // Javascript code, printing php code.
```

Comment: This is inside a <script> tag.  Adding content type headers for JS will not work how you think it might

Comment: tried it now, and it just printed out the entire html contents including the tags on the page.